# How to get into live mode in Sims Medieval?

Tags: sims-medieval

So, I've created my Sim and I wanted to build everything myself, but I didn't know for what these rooms were for.

So I decided to re-run the game and choose for second option, which stated it would use traditional set-up for Sim's castle. It looked wonderful, but I wasn't able to switch to Live Mode, where you can actually live and play.

I haven't changed anything. It's straight-forward. I just selected "Traditional set-up", created my Sim and then when I saw my castle, it was already greyed out.

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score -2):

Through trial and error it turns out you need to go to "Quests" and select the first mission and go all the way forward till you accept it. Do it, then the screen will automatically move you into your castle, and you will have Live Mode unlocked.

Comment: While you did find your answer i have downvoted both your question and answer because, as you have discovered (after 12 minutes) your answer was a Core Mechanic as such very little research effort went into your question